# Running jmeter tests in jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, gradle, jmeter, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I'm trying to run some jmeter tests in my jenkinsfile pipeline, but I'm getting some errors.

```
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':jmReport' (type 'TaskJMReports').
  - In plugin 'net.foragerr.jmeter' type 'net.foragerr.jmeter.gradle.plugins.TaskJMReports' property 'reportDir' is missing an input or output annotation.
```

This is how I'm trying to run it.

### build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id "net.foragerr.jmeter" version "1.0.5-2.13"
}

apply plugin: 'net.foragerr.jmeter'

jmeter {
    jmTestFiles = [file("src/test/jmeter/TestPlan.jmx")]  
    enableExtendedReports = true //produce Graphical and CSV reports 
}
```

### Pipeline

```
        stage('Run Non-Functional tests - Windows'){
            when { expression { env.OS == 'BAT' }}
            steps {                
                dir('') {
                    bat 'gradlew.bat jmReport'
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm also tried this away.

### build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id "de.qualersoft.jmeter" version "2.1.0"
}

tasks.register('jmRun',JMeterRunTask) {
    jmxFile.set("TestPlan.jmx")
}

tasks.register("jmReport",JMeterReportTask) {
    jmxFile.set("TestPlan.jmx")
    dependsOn("jmRun")
    deleteResults=true
}
```

The stage is the same and I'm getting this error.

```
> Could not get unknown property 'JMeterRunTask' for root project 'flowcrmtutorial' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

Why am I getting this errors?

Answer (score 0):

For the latter, you are missing the import as stated in the project's README:

https://github.com/qualersoft/jmeter-gradle-plugin#user-content-running-a-jmeter-test

> 1. Import `task` package.

```
import de.qualersoft.jmeter.gradleplugin.task.*

plugins {
    id "de.qualersoft.jmeter" version "2.1.0"
}
```

Comment: I added the import you mentioned and now I'm getting this error:
Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem loading XML from:'D:\ISEP\Mestrado\UnidadesCurriculares\1Ano\1Semestre\2022_2023\ODSOFT\odsoft-22-23-nmb-g303\src\test\jmeter\TestPlan.jmx'.
Cause:
CannotResolveClassException: kg.apc.jmeter.threads.UltimateThreadGroup
I'm using groovy.

Comment: I found that the problem was in my jmx file because I'm using the plugin jmeter-plugins-casutg-2.10.jar . How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you also forgot to add Custom Thread Groups plugin to your Jmeter configuration:

```
dependencies {
    jmeterPlugin("kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-casutg:2.10") {
        jmeter.tool.applyBomWorkaround(it)
    }
}
```

We must exclude bom dependency due to the kg.apc plugin features.